# setAuthConfig() not working for google calander auth

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api

i am trying to authenticate using setAuthConfig().
But i recieved an error.

**Fatal error**:  Uncaught exception 'Google_Exception' with message 'Invalid client secret JSON file.' in /var/www/myinvitebig.com/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Client.php:171
Stack trace:

## 0 /var/www/myinvitebig.com/calsync.php(57): Google_Client->setAuthConfig('cli.json')

## 1 {main}

thrown in **/var/www/myinvitebig.com/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Client.php** on line **171**

My cli.json file is correct.
Here is my code.
Please suggest me what to do?

```
$client->setAuthConfig('cli.json');
$client->refreshToken($rToken);
$refreshToken = $client->getAccessToken();

echo "==>".$refreshToken;
```

Comment: Hi harish try this approach  
paste your json file code inside setAuthConfig()

Answer (score 1):

setAuthConfig("Paste Your JSON file's code")